# SQL Server Data Security

Tags: sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, single-sign-on

I use SQL Server and have a SSO Database that contain application role, and application permissions for several my organization applications. several web service created for this database and each application work with these services. I want to restrict my application to get only and only own data from SSO database. and can't view, insert, delete or change role and permission for another applications.

what's the best practice for this problem.

Can I use App_Name() or Program_Name() for this purpose.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the app access to the tables, views etc, just make a well defined API using stored procedures.

Comment: You must execute your stored procedure by App parameter. and each one can execute these stored procedures with different parameter. I want each application owner can get only his application data from SSO Database.